# Adding a custom button to the advanced find robbon

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've got my customizations.xml importing ok, but when I open the Advanced Find Dialog, it tell me "Ribbon XML Validation Error":

[image]

I can't seem to get any more info than that.  Below is my customizations.xml text, I've tried to simplify it as much as possible.

---

```
<ImportExportXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Entities></Entities>
  <Roles></Roles>
  <Workflows></Workflows>
  <FieldSecurityProfiles></FieldSecurityProfiles>
  <Templates />
  <RibbonDiffXml>
    <CustomActions>
      <CustomAction Id="DEW.Mscrm.AdvancedFind.Groups.Debug.UploadFetchXml"
                    Location="Mscrm.AdvancedFind.Groups.Debug._children" >
        <CommandUIDefinition>
          <Button Id="DEW.Mscrm.AdvancedFind.Groups.Debug.UploadFetchXmlButton" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CustomAction>
    </CustomActions>
    <Templates>
      <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
    </Templates>
    <CommandDefinitions>
    </CommandDefinitions>
    <RuleDefinitions>
      <TabDisplayRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <EnableRules />
    </RuleDefinitions>
    <LocLabels />
  </RibbonDiffXml>
  <EntityMaps />
  <EntityRelationships />
  <OrganizationSettings />
  <optionsets />
  <Languages>
    <Language>1033</Language>
  </Languages>
</ImportExportXml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others looking to find the solution, or at least something to take note of if you're having a similar problem.

My problem was that the id for the different elements were the same.  You must have unique id's even among different elements.  And "Mscrm.AdvancedFind.Groups.Debug._children" should have been "Mscrm.AdvancedFind.Groups.Debug.Controls._children"